# Removing Duplicates Without CTEs Using Custom Sort Order SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
UserName | Score | Position | Class
Larry    | 0.12   | 1       | 2
Larry    | 0.13   | 2       | 2
Larry    | 0.12   | 3       | 2
Gale     | 0.112  | 4       | 2
Smith    | 0.1    | 5       | 2
Gale     | 0.21   | 6       | 2
Smith    | 0.42   | 7       | 2
Gale     | 0.112  | 8       | 2
Smith    | 0.42   | 9       | 2
```

What I need is to get unique **UserName** belonging to **Class 2**, along with the **highest score** and **best (lowest) position** i.e., out of the duplicates select the one with highest score and lowest position. Finally, sort the final result set using highest score and lowest position. For example, the above table should return:

```
Smith| 0.42 | 7 | 2
Gale | 0.21 | 6 | 2
Larry| 0.13 | 2 | 2
```

The query that I have come up with is as follows:

```
;WITH Filtered AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [Score]  DESC, [Position] --get unique UserNames getting the row with highest score and lowest position
            ) AS RowN
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
    WHERE [Class] = 2
)
SELECT *
FROM Filtered
WHERE RowN = 1
ORDER BY [Score] DESC, [Position] -- sort final set based on Score and Position
```

The question is that, does there exists a way where the same can be done without the CTE (or sub query or temp table or any holder for the result) and most possibly in a single select statement?

**T-SQL** is used for the said query.

Comment: This is a single `SELECT` statement.  It is one that happens to use a CTE.  It is also filtering on class = 3, not 2, so it is not consistent with. your question.

Comment: I have edited the typo, also the single select statement comment is directed towards the proposed solutions.

Comment: What is the motivation for not wanting to use a CTE? You've probably got the wrong idea about them.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement **terminator**  - not a kludge to avoid correcting the prior statement's lack of one (and your statement does not have one either)

Comment: @Tayyab **why** do you assume a solution without a CTE would be any better? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Using `ROW_NUMBER()` either in a CTE or subquery would require a single table scan only. In fact, since both `ROW_NUMBER` and the outer `ORDER BY` use the same sort order, the server may be able to perform only a single sort

Comment: I would re-iterate the concern about asking for this to be done without a CTE.  Understanding that SQL is a declarative language, and that it is essentially compiled to an execution plan, is probably useful knowledge for you to investigate.  Even better, growing an awareness that you're just assuming one pattern has resource or performance benefits over another, which is both a false assumption and a clearly untested one.  Finally, looking in to these matters before they materialise as real/concrete issues is the very essence of premature optimisation.

Comment: I suspect we are not going to find out *why* the OP is against CTEs; unfortunate as likely the answer to that will tell us what the *real* question being asked is. This effectively feels like intentionally asking for a different screwdriver when then one you've got is both the right shape and size for the screw you have, and the replacement you get is only either the right size or right shape (but not both).

Comment: @Larnu There exist multiple solution to the same problem, having said that I believe the only intention here is the same to learn if there is any way better to accomplish what is being done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Username,
       MAX(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY Username) Score,
       FIRST_VALUE(Position) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Score DESC, Position) Position,
       Class
FROM MyTable       
WHERE Class = 2
ORDER BY Score DESC, Position
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73c1e7555657cfa47e983ec32ac28948).

Comment: Damn, how could I forget those?! +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase this as:

```
select top (1) with ties username, score, min(position) as position, class
from t
where class = 2
group by username, score, class
order by row_number() over (partition by username order by score desc);
```

This would normally be *slower* than alternative methods that use a CTE or subqueries, but it seems to satisfy your desire for only one `SELECT`.

Comment: Although the returned result set is accurate, yet the final data is not sorted in the order as mentioned, probably you missed the Sort by Position.

Comment: Adding `position` to the `ORDER BY` clause would break this solution, @Tayyab , as then there are no ties.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to self-join the table. At least it works fine with the test data

```
select t1.username, max(t1.score) score, min(t2.position) position, t1.class
  from test t1
  join test t2
    on t1.username = t2.username 
 where t1.class = 2
 group by t1.username, t2.score, t1.class
having t2.score = max(t1.score) 
 order by score desc, position
```

Comment: @Tayyab does it? Have you compared the execution plans? This would require two table scans *and* spooling the grouped results before filtering them with `having`. On the other hand, using `ROW_NUMBER()` either in a CTE or subquery (they're equivalent) would require only a single scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it works however the performance is barely comparable to what is given in the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Tayyab what does `barely comparable` mean? What are the indexes? Execution plans? If all the involved fields are indexed there's no way a self join would be as fast, precisely because it has to calculate the intermediate group results.